# How to sign apk online using php?

Tags: php, android

Signing apk is easily can be done in Windows/Linux Os by cmd/shell .

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

I want to know is how to sign apk from hosting server. How to run these keytool and jarsigner in hosting cPanel/plesk by php script. Or something special is needed to process these operations.

Please kindly suggest me for this problem. Whether it can be or not ?

Comment: if you can install the tools on the server, then you can call shell with various php functions like `exec` `shell_exec` etc. If you cant install the tools, you need a different server

Comment: Thank you so much, your comment is v.helpful indeed. @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can use php exec function to run shell commands. [exec — Execute an external program](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)